# Using moodle to authenticate users to a web application

Tags: php, authentication, moodle

I'm developing a php web application to be used for a university. It needs the users to login before using some services. The university already has a moodle system in which all students and lecturers have accounts. Is there a way I can authenticate users to my web application using those moodle account usernames and passwords? (I don't need any other services from the moodle.)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to get the user information from Moodle, then you could use the External Services API to get it.

Hope this helps.